# No 5GHz networks seen on Arch Linux / MBP using BCM4331 card

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I recently installed Arch Linux on an old mid 2012 MacBook Pro with a Broadcom BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n WiFi card, but I can't find any 5GHz APs for some reason even though I'm using the [b43 driver](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Broadcom_wireless#b43).

`iwlist freq` only shows channels supporting 2.4GHz even though my particular MBP's network card should support 5GHz. What gives?

Do you know how I would go about changing the driver?

@K7AAY How do i know which version of b43 i am using? `lsmod` and `modinfo` only say b43. Howevery in `/lib/firmware` i do have two drivers one called b43 and one b43legacy. I guess i am already using the newer version?

Comment: Please post the Wi-Fi card,  just in case.

Comment: Broadcom BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n

Comment: What driver are you using for the card? Apparently for ubuntu there are [multiple drivers](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx)

Comment: Ah. Arch Linux Broadcom wireless: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Broadcom_wireless

Comment: That Arch linux page also mentions an issue with some cards not seeing access points which have high channel numbers, and suggests [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/749420/wireless-lost-ability-to-use-5ghz-pce-ac68) where the fix is to go to your AP and manually set the channel to a lower number.

Comment: i'm using b43 driver

Comment: Changing to a lower channel number had no effect

Comment: @xvy: To switch between drivers, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#Switching_between_drivers  Are you using http://aur.archlinux.org/packages/b43-firmware-classic or http://aur.archlinux.org/packages/b43-firmware ? _The latter is preferred_ per the Arch Wiki link you provided. Please find which firmware you used, click [edit] to respond and put the response in the question. Please don't use Add Comments, but instead use [edit].